# Lightweight solution to keep one table with million records

Tags: database, sqlite, aem

The brief: I need to have access to simply table with only one column, million rows, no any relationships, with just simle 6-character entries - postal codes. I will use it to check against user entered postal code to find out if it is valid. This will be temporary solution for a few monthes until I can remove this validation and leave it to web services. So right now I am seeking for solution to this.

What I have:

- Web portal build on top of Adobe CQ5 (Java, OSGi, Apache Sling, CRX)
- Linux environment where it is all situated
- plain text file (9mb) with these million rows

What I want:

- to have fast access to this data (only read, no write) for only one
  purpose: to find a row with specific value (six character length, contais only latin symbols and digits).
- create this solution as easier as possible, i.e. to use linux
  preinstalled software or with ability to quickly install and start it
  without long set up and configuring.

Currently I have the next options: use database or use something like HashSet to keep these million records. The first solution requires additional steps for installing and configuring database, the second solution drives me crazy when I think about whole million records in HashSet. So right now I am considering to try to use SQLite, but I want to hear some suggestions on this problem.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

**Storing in the content repository**

You could store it in the CQ5 repository to eliminate the external dependency on sqlite.  If you do, I would recommend structuring the storage hierarchically to limit the number of peer nodes.  For example, the postcode EC4M 7RF would be stored at:

```
/content/postcodes/e/c/4/m/ec4m7rf
```

This is similar to the approach that you will see to users and groups under /home.

This kind of data structure might help with autocomplete if you needed it also.  If you typed ec then you could return all of the possible subsequent characters for postcodes in your set by requesting something like:

```
/content/postcodes/e/c.1.json
```

This will show you the `4` (and the next character for any other postcode in `EC`).

You can control the depth using a numeric selector:

```
/content/postcodes/e/c.2.json
```

This will go down two levels showing you the `4` and the `M` and any postcodes in those 'zones'.

**Checking for non-existence using a Bloom Filter**
Also, have you considered using a [Bloom Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter)?  A bloom filter is a space efficient probabilistic data structure that can quickly tell you whether an item is *definitely not* in a set.  There is a chance of false positives, but you can control the probability vs size trade-off during the creation of the bloom filter.  There is no chance of false negatives.

There is a tutorial that demonstrates the concept [here](http://billmill.org/bloomfilter-tutorial/).

Guava provides and [implementation of the bloom filter](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/HashingExplained#BloomFilter) that is easily used.  It will work like the hashset, but you may not need to hold the whole dataset in memory.

```
BloomFilter<Person> friends = BloomFilter.create(personFunnel, 500, 0.01);
for(Person friend : friendsList) {
  friends.put(friend);
}
// much later
if (friends.mightContain(dude)) {
  // the probability that dude reached this place if he isn't a friend is 1%
  // we might, for example, start asynchronously loading things for dude while we do a more expensive exact check
}
```

Essentially, the bloom filter could sit in front of the check and obviate the need to make the check for items that are definitely in the set.  For items that maybe (~99% accurate depending on setup) in the set, then the check is made to rule out the false positive.

Comment: This is really interesting approach but as it seems to me has big disadvantages in the "preparing" part. I mean organize this one million rows into such structure. Currently we have all code including data and content is under svn organized as ecllipse projects. so the xml structure for such large amount of data will be  giant. And by the way this will be temporary solution, so later this whole bunch of nodes will become unnessessary, but I don't think CQ will easily remove such amount of nodes. But anyway great thanks to you for this approach.

Comment: Deleting the nodes shouldn't be a problem.  You can fire up crx explorer, select the root node that you wish to delete and choose ["Delete recursively"](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/crx/current/using_crx/content_explorer.html#par_9_table).

Comment: If you create all the nodes as content, then you can later enhance with a servlet to search the existing content.

Branching the tree by 1-3 char at each level helps manage the size of the tree and keeps things under the "10,000 child node" recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use redis memory database wich can handle millions of key/value pair and is blazing fast for loading or reading. Many connectors exists for all languages. and an apache module also exist ([mod_redis](https://github.com/sneakybeaky/mod_redis))

Answer (score 0):

You said that this is a temporary solution/requirement - so do you need a database?

You already have this as a text file - why not just load it into memory as part of your program as it's only 9 MB (assuming your process is persistent and always resident) and reference as an array or just a table of values.